# AngularJS Ng-repeat html separators / dividers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm, quite new to angular. I have a list item populated by some data :

```
<li ng-repeat="content in contents">
        <a class="item" href="#">
    <p><strong>{{content.Company}}</strong></p>
    <p>{{content.Town}}, {{content.PostCode}}</p>
    <p>{{content.Appointment}} at {{content.txtTime}}</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

and in my controller i am looping through the dates and formatting like :

```
angular.forEach($scope.contents, function(item){
                           item.Appointment = moment(item.Appointment).format('MMMM Do YYYY'); 

                       })
```

Im trying to add a html divider to seperate the appointments by date, so in the list it would say "today" then some appointments, "tommorow", "next week" etc.

Is this possible with angular..ive been trying to do this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used filters below. Instead of today, tomorrow and next week in my code, you can put in your conditions.

```
<li ng-repeat="content in contents|filter:filterFn">
        <a class="item" href="#">
    <p><strong>{{content.Company}}</strong></p>
    <p>{{content.Town}}, {{content.PostCode}}</p>
    <p>{{content.Appointment}} at {{content.txtTime}}</p>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-repeat="content in contents|filter:filterFn">
        <a class="item" href="#">
    <p><strong>{{content.Company}}</strong></p>
    <p>{{content.Town}}, {{content.PostCode}}</p>
    <p>{{content.Appointment}} at {{content.txtTime}}</p>
  </a>
</li>
<li ng-repeat="content in contents|filter:filterFn">
        <a class="item" href="#">
    <p><strong>{{content.Company}}</strong></p>
    <p>{{content.Town}}, {{content.PostCode}}</p>
    <p>{{content.Appointment}} at {{content.txtTime}}</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

In JS:

```
$scope.filterFn = function()
{
    // Do something

    // return something
};
```

Comment: I tried <li ng-repeat="content in contents|filter:{content.Appointment:'April 26th 2016'}"> but its blank

Comment: There is definitely some issue in content.Appointment then. Can you double check if April 26th 2016 is actually present in the Appointment field of any content?

Comment: This will be case sensitive, so be sure of that as well

Comment: This works : <li ng-repeat="content in contents|filter:'April 26th 2016'">.. how can i call a function instead of typing April 26th 2016?

Comment: Edited my answer to call a function on filter. The function will go in your controller.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Just one more thing, is it possible with these filters to add a date range?

Comment: You can do that in the function. while calling filterFn, pass the date as  a parameter, and in the function you can do a condition check

Answer (score 0):

you can use `angular-timeago` component to accomplish this, [link](https://github.com/yaru22/angular-timeago)